# comparison with logic problems

Tags: logic, number-comparison

I am a bit confused regarding the logic combined with size comparisons.
For example, if there is a statement

```
x > y -> x >= y
```

I believe that this would be true, as the former is a subset of the latter.
However, would the statement

```
x >=y -> x > y
```

also be considered true?
I believe in this case, the statement would be false.

To explain this, I was thinking about the combination of "or" in the if statement
that is:
if there exists a or in the if statement

```
(x > y or x = y)
```

the conclusion needs to satisfy both conditions in the or statement

```
x = y is not included in x > y
```

Would this be the correct understanding of logical comparisons?

Comment: Yes $x \ge y \to x \gt y$ is False. Consider the case with $0 \ge 0$, which is true.

Comment: And yes, your argument amounts to using [Proof by cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination): "the inference that if a statement $P$ implies a statement $Q$ and a statement $R$ also implies $Q$, then if either $P$ or $R$ is true, then $Q$ has to be true." In tour case, the part $x = y \to x > y$ does not hold.

Comment: I think you're reasoning is sound. On a logical level you decompose the assumption into an "or" statement, and then use that $a\wedge b\rightarrow a$ is true. To go further, you would go into the definitions of $\le$ $<$ and $=$, where $a<b$ may be defined as $a\le b$ and not $a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

In logic: 
$x\geq y \iff x>y \lor x=y$ is true.

But, $x\geq y\implies x>y$ is not a valid inference, because:
$p\lor q$ does not tautologically imply $p$

So your naive set approach is correct reasoning .